# In Java, is it possible to (statically) import constructors or local variables?

Tags: java, import, static-import

Or can this just be done for methods/fields/enum constants?

Comment: use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes. If you overuse the static import feature, it can make your program unreadable and unmaintainable See Effective Java Item 17: Constant Interface Antipattern , static imports tempts to declare local copies of constants!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors in Java can't be invoked directly (only via `new`), so you can't import them apart from the containing class. Since the only use of a constructor, is to create a new instance of the class, you need to import the whole class anyway, and this implies the constructor. Not to mention that if anything, it is an instance method, and you can import only `static` methods and variables.

Local variables have no existence outside their scope, i.e. they are not tied to a class, only to a code block inside a method *[Update]*(or a static/instance initializer)*[/Update]*. So how would you import them?

Comment: But have in mind that local variables can also appear inside class/enums' instance/static initializers.

Comment: @John, good point, although it does not change anything regarding importability. I extended my answer nevertheless.

Comment: @John: Local variables remain local. They aren't part of a class so you can't import them. Basically you can only import things that are static.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

In order to import method or variable it should be public and static. Constructors and local variables cannot be static.